# How do I make a JButton display 2 different modes every time I click it?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, action

I am trying to implement a JButton that displays Connect or Disconnect depending on whether or not it is connected to the server. So, when I click the button when it says Connect, it'll connect to the server, and then it will show Disconnect. When I click Disconnect, it'll disconnect from the server and the button will show connect again. However, when I click the button, nothing happens.

```
        btnConnect.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

                if (btnConnect.getText().equals("Connect")){
                    btnConnect.setText("Disconnect");

                try {
                    int portNum = 5520;
                    String hostAddress = Actual_IP_Address.getText();
                    sock = new Socket(hostAddress, portNum);
                    writeSock = new PrintWriter ( sock.getOutputStream(), true);
                    readSock = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
                    sock = null;
                }
                }
                if (btnConnect.getText().equals("Disconnect")){
                    btnConnect.setText("Connect");

                try {
                    readSock.close();
                    writeSock.close();
                    sock.close();
                    sock = null;
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
                    sock = null;
                }

        }
            }}
        );
```

How come when I click the button it merely shows Connect?

Comment: On a side note, not use `MouseListener` for this, use a `ActionListener`, as a button may be "actioned" via the keyboard as well as the mouse ;)

Comment: You socket and UI logic should also be separated, you're running the risk of blocking the UI until the socket completes writing/reading (which may actually be the cause of your overarching issue - the UI won't update till you exit the `mouseClicked` method).  I'd use an observer pattern instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the basic outline of your code is

```
if (button.getText().equals("Connect"){
   button.setText("Disconnect")
}

if (button.getText().equals("Disconnect"){
   button.setText("Connect")
}
```

It looks like what is happening is that you are changing your button text value to "Disconnect" like you should be. But then immediately after, you once again check if the button text value is equal to "Disconnect" and change it again. Change your two if statements to be an else-if statement instead

```
if (button.getText().equals("Connect"){
   button.setText("Disconnect")
} else if (button.getText().equals("Disconnect"){
   button.setText("Connect")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This "basic" problem is, when connected, you set the button text to `Disconnect` and then promptly check to see if the text is `Disconnect` and set it back to `Connect`.

The larger problem is you're coupling your code, which will make it hard to manage and keep the UI in sync with what is actually going on - what happens if the socket disconnects unexpectedly.

Another issue is, you're potentially, blocking the UI, which cause it to "freeze" and become unresponsive, as it might take a few seconds for the socket to establish.

A better solution would be to try and decouple the UI from the socket and rely on some kind of observer pattern so you could be notified when the socket state changes, regardless of whether the UI stopped the socket or it stopped due to some other condition.

Personally, I'd use a `SwingWorker` for this, as it allows you to overload long running/blocking operations to another thread, but provides a number of useful mechanisms for delivering updates back to the UI thread (ie the Event Dispatching Thread) safely, for example...

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton doStuff;
        private SocketWorker worker;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            doStuff = new JButton("Connect");
            doStuff.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    if (worker == null) {
                        doStuff.setText("...");
                        worker = new SocketWorker("hostname");
                        worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                                if ("state".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                                    System.out.println(worker.getState());
                                    switch (worker.getState()) {
                                        case STARTED: 
                                            doStuff.setText("Disconnect");
                                            break;
                                        case DONE: 
                                            worker = null;
                                            doStuff.setText("Connect");
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        worker.execute();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("...");
                        try {
                            worker.stop();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        doStuff.setText("Connect");
                    }
                }
            });
            add(doStuff);
        }

    }

    public class SocketWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        private Socket socket;
        private String hostName;

        private PrintWriter writeSock;
        private BufferedReader readSock;

        public SocketWorker(String hostName) {
            this.hostName = hostName;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            // This is just here to demonstrate the point
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            //int portNum = 5520;
            //socket = new Socket(hostName, portNum);
            //writeSock = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            //readSock = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));        

            // Do your socket handling here...

            return null;
        }

        public void stop() throws IOException {
            if (socket == null) { return; }

            socket.close();
        }

    }
}
```

In this example, I've just used `Thread.sleep` to put a "mocked" operation in place.  I'd consider doing all your reading/writing to the socket through the worker and keep it alive until the socket it closed (for what ever reason).  But, this will demonstrate how the button can be updated no based on the state of the click, but based on the state of the worker itself

Take a look at [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) and [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details